# Does FluentAssertions support WithStrictOrdering for dictionaries?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, fluent-assertions

I'm comparing two simple dictionaries. I add items to the dictionaries in opposite order. I'm using the WithStrictOrdering option in FluentAssertions but this test passes and I think it should fail:

```
var actual = new Dictionary<string, string>();
actual.Add("a", "1");
actual.Add("b", "2");

var expected = new Dictionary<string, string>();
expected.Add("b", "2");
expected.Add("a", "1");

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithStrictOrdering());
```

When I look at these dictionaries in the debugger, the items appear to be in different order, as expected. I can use the WithStrictOrdering option for lists and it behaves as expected. Does the WithStrictOrdering option work for dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WithStrictOrdering` is ignored when comparing two dictionaries.

In Fluent Assertions two dictionaries are consider equivalent if:

- the two dictionaries have the same length, and
- for every key in the expectation, the subject contains a value for that key (respecting its `comparer`) that is *equivalent* to the value for the same key in the expectation.

The source code is found [here](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/develop/Src/FluentAssertions/Equivalency/GenericDictionaryEquivalencyStep.cs).

Regarding the order you're observing through the debugger:
The order of elements may change, e.g. if the Dictionaries are re-hashed.
In general you should not rely on the order of elements in a `Dictionary`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

If you still want to compare the elements in two dictionaries respecting the *undefined* order of retrieving the elements a workaround is to cast the `Dictionary<string,string>` to an `IEnumerable<object>`

```
actual.Cast<object>().Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithStrictOrdering());
```

Note: In Fluent Assertions V5 using `Cast<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()` will also work, but in the upcoming V6 a type implementing `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` is considered to be a dictionary-like type and hence `Cast<object>()` is necessary to make `Should()` resolve to `GenericCollectionAssertions` instead of `GenericDictionaryAssertions`.